# Running Task scheduler Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I am currently on a project which requires me to send emails to registered users, and i implemented the queuing method, it works fine when i am on my localhost running artisan commands. And i tried to step it up to use a development server Heroku, but i find it pretty hard to do. Went to the laravel docs and added the cron entry then scheduled my artisan command, but it does not still process.

```
//code
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

1. Is the path/to actually suppose to be the path to my project i.e project folder name?
2. If not is there an alternative way to run this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, path to artisan is the full path to your project directory. This has the artisan executable in it.

I am not aware of another way to run the scheduler. Cron is a reliable way to do these types of things.

Comment: i tired it does not still run the tasks